# Non-constant continuous map from $\mathbb{R}P^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

Give an example of non-constant continuous map from $\mathbb{R}P^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

My attempt: Since $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is closed unit disc with antipodal points of the boundary identified. I will restrict the projection map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$ to closed unit disc. then can i use this to get the required map.

Comment: If you have a metric $d$ on a set $X$, then $f(x)=d(x_0,x)$ is always a continuous map $X\to\mathbb R$, for any $x_0\in X$.

Comment: why is d a metric??

Comment: Why is what a metric?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews is RP2 metrizable?

Comment: It is, but you'd need to show it is. And it depends on how you define $\mathbb RP^2$ how you'd define a metric. Probably easiest if $\mathbb RP^2$ is defined as the sphere with anti-podal points identified.

Comment: Embed in $\mathbb{RP}^2$ in some $\mathbb{R}^n$ and take a coordinate map.

Answer (score 2):

Try $[x : y : z] \mapsto \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}.$

Comment: Why did u think about this map

Comment: I wanted something with polynomials that is well defined on $RP^2$, so something like $p/q$ where $p$ and $q$ are homogenous would work. Then I needed to ensure $q$ never vanishes(on the specified domain), and for this the sum of squares works.

Comment: since RP2 is a topological manifold and this map is continuous in the standard coordinate charts of RP2 I believe it follows it is continous. it looks pretty continuous anyway. you can also check it is nonconstant by plugging in some values

Answer (score 2):

Let $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ denote the closed unit disc in $\mathbb{C}$ and consider the map $f : \overline{\mathbb{D}} \to \overline{\mathbb{D}}$ given by $f(z) = z^2$. If $z, w \in \partial\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ are antipodal points, then $f(z) = f(w)$ so the map descends to a map $\hat{f} : \mathbb{RP}^2 \to \overline{\mathbb{D}}$ satisfying $\hat{f}([z]) = f(z)$. The map $|\hat{f}|$ is then a continuous non-constant map $\mathbb{RP}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for any manifold: Let $U \subset M$ be an open set homeomorphic to the unit disk $B$ in $\mathbb R^n$ via a homeomorphism $\varphi : U\to B$. Then define $f : M\to \mathbb R$,

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \max\{-|\varphi (x)|+1/2, 0\} & \text{if }x\in U, \\ 0 &\text{if } x\notin U.\end{cases}$$

(That is, find a continuous nonconstant function on $B$ with compact support and then extend the function on $M$ and setting other points to be zero)

Answer (score -2):

Indentify $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $\mathbb{C}$ and consider the map $\nu\colon \mathbb{C}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which takes $z$ to its norm $\nu(z)=|z|$.

Comment: This gives you a map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{RP}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.